# Python TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the below script to make request to google. However, when I execute it, I get the error stating:

**client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**

On browsing for similar issues in stackoverflow, **client.sendto** has been recommended to use along with encoding the message. However, in my case there is no message that is passed.

The below is the script I use:

```
import socket
target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host,target_port))
client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")
response = client.recv(4096)
print(response)
```

Any pointers on correcting the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "there is no message"? You are clearly sending an HTTP request.

Comment: In Python 3, `""GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n"` is a unicode string and `.send()` wants bytes to send over the wire. Your code tries to send the unicode string straight without encoding, which the error message rightfully complains about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to choose an [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html), example:

```
client.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n".encode(encoding='utf-8'))
```

See also: [Python Socket Send Buffer Vs. Str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411864/python-socket-send-buffer-vs-str) and [TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)